# How to get text value of a HyperLinkField

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I had a boundfield:

```html
<asp:BoundField DataField="Site ID" HeaderText="Site ID" SortExpression="Full ID" />
```

At a certain point in my code I was getting its text value like this "row.Cells(3).Text":

```html
        For Each row As GridViewRow In gvShow.Rows
            Dim cbx As CheckBox = row.FindControl("ChkSigleItem")

            If cbx.Checked Then
                strSelectedItems = strSelectedItems & Trim(row.Cells(3).Text) & ";"
            End If

        Next
```

Now, I had to transform the BoundField into a HyperLinkField and using "row.Cells(3).Text" to get the text value doesn't work anymore, the string is empty.

This is my HyperLinkField:

```html
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Site ID" HeaderText="Site ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="sitecard.aspx?id={0}" DataTextField="Site ID" SortExpression="Full ID" />
```

Any idea on how I can solve this?

Many thanks.
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Forget about it, I have found the answer, I was just missing a bracket in my tests.

solution:

```html
strSelectedItems = strSelectedItems & Trim(DirectCast(row.Cells(3).Controls(0), HyperLink).Text) & ";"
```